# Finding an expression for a joint probability if two random variables have the same distribution function.

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the same distribution function, say $F$, find an expression for $P(X<t, Y<t)$.

My attempt: $P(X<t, Y<t) = P(X<t)P(Y<t) = \int_{-\infty}^t f(x)dx \int_{-\infty}^t f(y)dy = [\int_{-\infty}^t f(x)dx]^2$.

How can I use this to find the distribution function $H(z)$ of the variable $Z=max(X,Y)$?

Comment: $a\times a =2a$ or $a\times a=a^2$? Why isn't the answer $[F(t)]^2$ or $[F(t^-)]^2$ if you want to nitpick about continuity?

Comment: Thank you. I just fixed it.

Comment: Is it to be assumed that the distribution of $X$ is continuous?

Comment: Yes, I believe the distribution of $X$ is continuous. Thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$\max{(X,Y)} < t \iff (X<t)\cap(Y<t)$$
so
$$\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}(\max{(X,Y)} < t) & = \Bbb{P}(\ (X<t)\cap(Y<t)\ )\\
& = \Bbb{P}(X<t)\ \Bbb{P}(Y<t)\\
& = F(t)\ F(t).
\end{align}$$

Similarly, 
$$\min{(X,Y)} \ge t \iff (X\ge t)\cap(Y\ge t)$$
so
$$\begin{align}
\Bbb{P}(\min{(X,Y)} \ge t) & = \Bbb{P}(\ (X\ge t)\cap(Y\ge t)\ )\\
& = \Bbb{P}(X\ge t)\ \Bbb{P}(Y\ge t)\\
1 - \Bbb{P}(\min{(X,Y)} < t) & = (1-\Bbb{P}(X< t))\ (1-\Bbb{P}(Y< t))\\
& = (1-F(t))\ (1-F(t))\\
\Bbb{P}(\min{(X,Y)} < t) & = 1 - (1-F(t))^2.
\end{align}$$
It is assumed that the distribution of $X$ is continuous (or that the CDF is defined using "$\lt$" rather than "$\le$").

Comment: Thank you r.e.s. Then how would $min(X,Y)$ work out in this scenario?

Comment: @MathDamon - I've added that to the answer.